# Normalize distance between U.S. counties so that adjacent counties are unit distance away

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude, adjacency

High level problem: I'd like a "distance" metric that measures adjacency rather than euclidean distance.

Details: I'm looking for a way to normalize distance between U.S. counties so that adjacent counties are unit distance away. Right now I have latitude / longitude centroids for each county (or, if you'd like I can convert that to some x-y coordinate space since lat/lon might be problematic). Then I can compute the distance (e.g., in miles) between any two counties. My issue is that I'd like a "distance" that accounts for the fact that miles in Texas are very different from miles in New Jersey (two adjacent counties in Texas may be dozens of miles away, whereas two adjacent counties in NJ might only be a few miles, but in the end they are still adjacent neighbors and neighboring pairs should be treated the same no matter where you are in the country). Finally, I want the centroids for each county in this new space so that I have a final x-y coordinate for each county.

Below is a map which can hopefully illustrate my point. Counties on the west coast (Nevada, for example) are much bigger on average, so the distance (in miles) between the centroids of two neighboring counties is large. On the East cost (Ohio, for example), counties are smaller, so the distance between the neighboring counties is smaller (in miles). So the "distance in miles" metric (when measuring closeness in terms of adjacency) highly depends on where you are in the U.S.

[image]

I'm imagining a map of the U.S. where small dense clusters of counties on the East Coast are spread out and the large counties in the West are shrunk so that I can measure distance in a way that is invariant to where I'm measuring within the U.S.

Input/output: So input is (1) county centroids and (2) pairwise distances between adjacent counties and output would be normalized county centroids.

Question: Is there a standard way of doing this? I'm not even certain what terms to google in order to find a solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. More details please. A picture would help.

Comment: @Pointdump I've added some details. If there is something specific that is confusing I can expand.

Comment: So you sort of want to measure the "adjaceny order" of two arbitrary county polygons, e.g. when county A is adjacent to county B, the distance from A to B is 1. But if C is adjacent to B but C is not adjacent to A, then the distance from A to C is 2 (sum of AB=1 and BC=1). I understand the concept up to this point, but I don't see how you can make a new cartesian grid on this basis. You could do some kind of force-directed graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing

Comment: Unsure if this helps but this script will attribute adjacent polygons in increasing order. You would need some scripting skills in ArcGIS to create a new attribute column, select a county, attribute that county with a value of 1 then run the script linked here:  https://github.com/LummiGIS/Attribute-adjacent-geometries-with-increasing-count-values.  You would need to do this for every county or create a copy of the data for every county and run the tool on each copy.